# How to Copy Part of json?

Tags: javascript, json, api, github

I get information from github's api, but some of the returned data I don't want.The following is my code for filtering json data.
However, it is too complicated to write every field. Is there a more convenient way to write it?

```
     result => {
    var obj2 = {

        items: []
    }

    function ObjectCreate(id, tags, score, link, title) {
        this.title = title
        this.link = link
        this.score = score
        this.id = id.toString();
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    var need = results.items
    for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {

        var obj = new ObjectCreate(i, need[i].tags, need[i].score, need[i].link, need[i].title);
        obj2.items.push(obj);

    }
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj2, "", "\t")
}
```

Comment: please share the sample data

Comment: You can use destructing assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let data = [{'id':120,'title': 'hello','link': '#', 'score': 24,'tags': 'tags blah blah','location': 'US','price': 120,},{'id':12,'title': 'hello wprld', 'link': '#','score': 125,'tags': 'tags blah blah', 'location': 'SO','price': 12,}
]

const format = data.map( ({id,link,title,score,tags}, index) => ({id:index,link,title,score,tags}))

console.log(format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

```
 const format = ({ items }) => ({ 
    items: items.map((el, id) => ({ id, title: el.title, link: el.link, score: el.score, tags: el.tags }))
 });
```

Or using some helper functions:

```
const lens = (key, fn) => obj => ({ ...obj, [key]: fn(obj[key]) });
const pick = (...keys) => obj => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: obj[k] })));
const map = (...fns) => arr => arr.map((el, i) => fns.reduce((el, fn) => fn(el, i), el));

const format = lens("items",
  map(
    pick("title", "link", "score", "tags"), 
    (el, index) => el.id = index
  )
);
```